# Is anti-Brahminism a sin according to scriptures?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins

Is [anti-Brahminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Brahminism) in accordance with Hinduism and its scriptures? Is it a sin or is it glorified?

Comment: Today's Brahmins are not the kind of Brahmins who are praised in the scriptures .. so why are u bringing in today's context?

Comment: @Rickross There are still lots of Brahmins who follow scriptures, and so it is still relevant today. Why people keep downvoting this?

Comment: Chill bro.. no exemption for any state, now a days majority Brahmins are doing lot of things never like before thousands of years (alcohol, gambling, xxx etc..)

Comment: @CR241 I'm not talking about those fake Brahmins. I'm talking about learned Brahmins and the like.

Comment: @Ishvaku you should change your question to be more generic like 'Is Anti-Brahmanism in accordance with Hinduism and its scriptures? Is it a sin or is it glorified?' else your question will be considered opinion based as it is stating your particular belief for Tamil Nadu. So, please edit your question if you want your question to stay open.

Comment: @Aby How about I remove the Tamil Nadu reference from the question? I think the title as is seem's fine.

Comment: @Ikshvaku there are still many village places in India and more places especially South India, Tamil Nadu who still follow the cultural heritage from ancient times. Infact South Indians first stood against western beliefs.... Before writing about anything kindly do research and write... Your questions are direct and target.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### [Anti-Brahminism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Brahminism) is a sin and against the rules of Hindu scripture.

The various Dharma Shastras prescribe various punishments for different types of abuse hurled at Brahmanas.

**Verbal abuse:**

From *[Manusmriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201199.html)*:

> On [verbally] abusing a Brāhmaṇa the Kṣatriya
>   should be fined one hundred; and the Vaiśya one hundred and fifty; or
>   two hundred; **the Śūdra however deserves immolation.**-(267)
>
> "For the Śūdra ‘immolation,’—in the form of beating, cutting off the
>   tongue, actual death, and so forth, to be adjusted in accordance, with
>   the exact nature of the abuse."
>
> If a once-born person [Shudra and below] insults a twice-born one with
>   gross abuse, **he should suffer the cutting off of his tongue; as he is
>   of low origin.**—(270)
>
> If he mentions the name and caste of these men with scorn, a burning
>   iron nail ten inches long shall be thrust into his mouth.—(271)
>
> **If through arrogance**, he teaches brāhmaṇas their duty, the king shall
>   pour heated oil into his mouth and ears.—(272)

Other *Dharma Shastras* regarding verbal abuse:

> Gautama (12. 1, 8, 10-13).—‘A Śūdra who intentionally reviles
>   twice-born men, by criminal abuse, or criminally assaults them with
>   blows, **shall be deprived of the limb with which he has offended.**
>
> Yājñavalkya (2.206.207).—‘The fine is half for reviling one lower than
>   one’s self, double, **for reviling women and superior persons**; thus
>   shall the fine be **inflicted in accordance with the superiority or
>   inferiority of the castes concerned.**
>
> Viṣṇu (5.23, 33-35-38).—‘If the Śūdra uses abusive language, his
>   tongue shall be cut off;
>
> Āpastamba (2.27.14).—‘The tongue of a Śūdra who speaks evil of a
>   virtuous person, belonging to one of the first three castes, shall be
>   cut out.’
>
> Bṛhaspāti (20.6-11).—The Śūdra shall be compelled to pay the fine of
>   the first amercement for abusing a Vaiśya; the middle amercement for
>   abusing a Kṣatriya 5 and the highest amercement for abusing a
>   Brāhmaṇa.’

**Physical assault:**

From *[Manusmriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201212.html)*:

> With whatever limb the low-born man hurts a superior person, every
>   such limb of his shall be cut off; this is the teaching of Manu.—(279)
>
> If he raises his hand or a stick, he should have his hand cut off; if
>   he strikes in anger with the foot, his foot shall be cut off.—(280)
>
> If, out of arrogance, he spits, the king should have his two lips cut
>   off; if he urinates, then his penis; and if he breaks wind, his
>   anus.—(282)    If he catches hold of the hair, the king shall
>   unhesitatingly have his hands out off; also if he lays hold of the
>   feet, the beard, the neck, or the scrotum.—(283)

### Should politicians support Brahmins or be against them? According to scriptures, the politicians are obligated to support Brahmins:

> Manu 9.313 - Even when fallen in the deepest distress, the king shall
>   not provoke the Brāhmaṇas; for if provoked, they would ruin him, along
>   with his army and conveyances.
>
> Manu 9.317 - Learned or unlearned, **the Brāhmaṇa is a great divinity**;
>   just as consecrated or unconsecrated, the fire is a great divinity.
>
> Manu 9.319 - Similarly even though they betake themselves to all sorts
>   of undesirable acts, **yet Brāhmaṇas should be honoured in every
>   way**; for they are the greatest divinity.
>
> Manu 9.322 - The Kṣatriya flourishes not without the Brāhmaṇa; the
>   Brāhmaṇa prospers not without the Kṣatriya; **the Brāhmaṇa and the
>   Kṣatriya, when united, prosper here as also in the other world.**
>
> Gautama (11.14).—‘It is declared in the Veda—“Kṣatriyas, who are
>   assisted by Brāhmaṇas, prosper and do not fall into distress.”’
>
> Vaśiṣṭha (19.4).—‘It is declared in the Veda—“A realm where a Brāhmaṇa
>   is appointed domestic priest prospers.”’

But this doesn't mean that Brahmanas shouldn't be punished, for the commentator Medhatithi says:

> When they betake themselves to forbidden acts, they shall be dealt and
>   punished according to law, gently, and not attacked with force, in the
>   manner of other castes.

Also Narada:

> Nārada (18.12).—‘On account of their dignity and sanctity, it is not
>   permitted to either advise or rebuke a King or a Brāhmaṇa, unless they
>   swerve from the path of duty.’

By "advise" it actually means "criticize," since kings have advisers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88829/discussion-on-answer-by-ikshvaku-is-anti-brahminism-a-sin-according-to-scripture).